# ¿GPS Glonass Ublox7 with nmea_serial_driver?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I am trying to connect a GPS Usb Glonass Ublox7 with nmea_serial_driver and I can't. I have checked where it is connected using ls / dev / tty * and I have it connected in ttyACM1.

If I run the command:
$ sudo cat /dev/ttyACM1 
or 
$ sudo cat /dev/gps1

I get NMEA sentence. However when executing the command:

$ rosrun nmea_serial_driver _port:/dev/ttyACM1 _baud:=115200

I get the following error that can't open port

The Glonass GPS supports any standard baud rate.

If I run the following command:
$ groups

I get the following:
: lauratfg adm dialout fax cdrom floppy tape sudo audio dip video plugdev input nopasswdlogin lpadmin scanner gpio i2c spi sambashare samba

I don't know what else to do ... Help please. This gps doesn't work with nmea_serial_driver?

Thank you. Greetings.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364273/%C2%BFgps-glonass-ublox7-with-nmea_serial_driver?/) by [patrickfonty](https://answers.ros.org/users/61642/patrickfonty/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2020-10-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was that I had the gpsd daemon installed.
The solution has been to find which process was using the port for this I opened a terminal with the following command:
$ ps aux
After this, all the processes appear in the terminal. I looked for the one called gpsd which had a number assigned for example 3223.
I opened another terminal and ran the following command:
$ sudo kill -9 3223
From here, I was able to run the node nmea_serial_driver. I also recommend disabling bluetooth

---

Originally posted by [patrickfonty](https://answers.ros.org/users/61642/patrickfonty/) with karma: 26 on 2021-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-01-26**:
Congratulations.